# FFT2 Non-zero imaginary part for centro-symmetric object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fft, interpolation

I'm currently testing the `fft` package from `numpy`. I created an artificial centro-symmetric image and I made a 2D FFT on it, I took the imaginary part and remarked that this is not equal to zero. I don't understand why, do you have any idea? Maybe there is something that I miss when I goes from 1D radial profile to a 2D image, I really don't know...

NEW UPDATE (new example) :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


I_min = 1.774E-6 #min(y_intensity[y_intensity!=0])
y = np.ones(50) #y_intensity[:50]
xv_3 = np.linspace(0,0.005,len(y))*1E3# x_intensity[:50]*1E3

new_r = np.linspace(-100,100,2**8)
interpol_index = interpolate.interp1d(xv_3, y)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(new_r,new_r)
profilegrid3 = np.ones(X.shape, float)
for i, x in enumerate(X[0, :]):
    for k, z in enumerate(Y[:, 0]):
        current_radius = np.sqrt(x**2 + z**2)
        
        cond=np.logical_or(current_radius>=max(xv_3),current_radius<=min(xv_3))
        if cond == True :
            profilegrid3[i, k] = I_min

        else :
            profilegrid3[i, k] = interpol_index(current_radius)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.imag(np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fft2(np.fft.fftshift(profilegrid3)))))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Image :

[image]

Imaginary Part :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Use `ifftshift` to convert an image with the origin in the middle to have the origin in the top-left corner where the FFT expects it. And use `fftshift` to convert the output of the FFT to have the origin in the middle. (You’re using these the wrong way around.) But note that these two functions do exactly the same thing for even-sized arrays, so you will not notice a difference after you fix this.
2. Your input must have the origin at `size//2`. The way you create `new_r` means that the origin falls right in between pixels. I think that adding `endpoint=False` to your `np.linspace` call fixes this.

Comment: This works perfectly ! Thank you for all of those precisions :) Didn't know the endpoint trick and thanks for the fftshift enlightenment !